# How to design a text editor in QT?

Tags: qt, architecture

I want to design a text editor in QT and planning to implement the following basic features,

1) Basic editing features like cut,paste,formatting,indentation etc.

2) Auto completion based on the context.(Based on some xml input file)

3) Syntax highlighting ( based on some xml input file )

Can you please suggest some approaches for the overall architecture/design?

Comment: Just to be sure: you have seen http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html and http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcompleter.html (and http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/tools-customcompleter.html)?

Comment: Thanks. I looked in to those examples. But I want to know how these different modules like completer, syntax highlighter fit together to create solid design for the editor.

Comment: You need to learn Qt basics to be able combine this sources together in one application...

Comment: I am aware of QT basics and also I have a small working prototype. The problem in hand is not about the implementation, but on "How to design /architect" the editor?

Comment: You really need bounty? You may lost +50 rep, because if no answers will be accepted, you loss them...

Comment: You can refer my repository [textEditor](https://github.com/JosanSun/textEditor)

Answer (score 18):

How about:

1. [Application Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html)
2. [Completer Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-completer-example.html) or [Custom Completer Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html)
3. [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html)

All this things are stored in one single place, in you Qt SDK examples

Comment: And in fact, QSyntaxHighlighter class is really, really slow sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

**This post is in 2015. NO DEAD LINKS**

As @mosg mentioned.

In the menu bar. Go to Help > Index:
and in the search field look for:

1. Application Example
2. Completer Example
3. QSyntaxHighlighter

That would help you to begin.

Comment: It was better to update the accepted answer than post a separate one. This answer does not add anything significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

If using Python is an option for you, you might find my [Qt Text Editor example on GitHub useful](https://github.com/pyqt/examples/tree/_/src/07%20Qt%20Text%20Editor). It uses PyQt5 (but you can also use PySide2) to implement a minimal text editor. Some screenshots:

[image: Qt Text Editor Windows]
[image: QMenu example]
[image: Qt QMenu]
[image: QDialog example]
[image: QMessageBox example]

It doesn't do formating, autocompletion or syntax highlighting but should still be a pretty good starting point. Maybe you can use `QTextEdit` and `QSyntaxHighlighter` to get these features.